# Examples of spaces in which the closure of any path connected set is path connected.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Are there (non-trivial) examples of topological spaces in which the closure of any path connected set is path connected?

If so, are there any far reaching topological consequences of this property? Can the spaces be described?

Comment: Pardon me if this is a stupid question, but wouldn't $R$ be a nontrivial example of such a space?  How about any union of open subsets of $R$?  How about any finite union of intervals?

Comment: @MJD: No, it's very false in $\Bbb R^n$ for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Any totally disconnected space is an example (for example, the Cantor set). Indeed, the only path-connected subsets of it are singletons, which are already closed!

(Perhaps not so interesting, but hey, the Cantor set isn't exactly trivial! :))

I don't think that this property is particularity "characteristic". Path components can be pretty silly in an arbitrary space, because the topology can be quite incompatible with the topology of the interval. You might want to add some restrictions on the kind of space that you're looking for.

Comment: Restrictions like requiring it to be path-connected and/or completely regular?

Comment: @dfeuer No idea. I suppose the burden lies on the OP. I'm not sure this property is ever of interest, to be honest. It doesn't seem like a natural property to me.

Comment: @Marie It is for that reason that I find it interesting, actually- because it is very *un* natural.  All examples I have seen are completely pathological, i.e. totally disconnected, discrete topology, etc.  This makes me wonder if the property is so extreme that these are the only possible examples...

Comment: So, with respect to @dfeuer's suggestion, I'd love to see an example in either of those cases, assuming it's possible.

Comment: @SamuelHandwich, you mean non-trivial examples other than connected subsets of $\Bbb R$, I gather.

Comment: @dfeuer Right.${}$